# Central Limit Theorem for a Lévy Process (mild assumptions)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem, levy-processes

I want to discuss the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) of a Lévy process  under some assumptions.
The answer of the previous post [Central Limit Theorem for Lévy Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614615/central-limit-theorem-for-l%C3%A9vy-process) required a wide base of knowledge, without any assumptions on the Lévy process. So I'm considering now a more specific setup:

**Setup:**
Given a Lévy process on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $E|X_1|<\infty$ (thus $E|X_t|<\infty$ for $t>0$) and finite second moment for all $t\geq 0$. Let $\Sigma$ be the positive definite covariance Matrix of $X_1$.
Then for $n:=\lceil t \rceil$ or $n:=\lfloor t \rfloor$ then 
$$
X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_1
$$
is considered (due to the Lévy property) as a partial sum of $n$ i.i.d. variables. 
Then by CLT we have 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{X_n}{n}-E[X_1]\right) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}\left(0,\Sigma\right) \text{ as } n\rightarrow \infty
$$
with covariance Matrix $\Sigma$.

**From this I want to conclude, that the CLT holds for real values $t$ also.(so I may avoid the proof a new CLT in continuous time for this given setup i.e. by characteristic functions).
So**
\begin{align}
\sqrt{t}\left(\frac{X_t}{t}-E[X_1]\right) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}\left(0,\Sigma\right) \text{ as } t \rightarrow \infty
\end{align}

**My idea** Reduce the setting to the classical CLT by splitting up. Choose $n:=\lfloor t \rfloor$
\begin{align} 
\frac{X_t}{t}=\frac{n}{t}\left(\frac{X_n}{n}+\frac{X_t-X_n}{n}\right) \tag 1
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sqrt{t} \left(\frac{n}{t}\left(\frac{X_n}{n}+\frac{X_t-X_n}{n}\right)-E[X_1]\right)
\end{align}
Define $U_n:=\frac{1}{n} \sup_{t\in [n,n+1]}|X_t-X_n|$. $U_n$ is i.i.d. Since $E|X_{1}|<\infty$ it follows that $U_1$ has finite expectation, see
[Finite supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650849/l%C3%A9vy-process-existence-of-the-expectation-of-the-supremum-of-the-past-process). By classical Law of Large Number we have 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n U_{n}\rightarrow E[U_1]\quad P\text{-a.s.}
\end{align} such that $n^{-1}U_{n}\rightarrow 0$ $P\text{-a.s.}$ (as $n\rightarrow \infty$ by $t\rightarrow \infty$) which implies convergence in distribution. Note that $U_n$ dominates the second term in the brackets in $(1)$.

Then we can conclude from that, that (remark that $n:=\lfloor t \rfloor$)
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{X_t}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{t} \frac{X_{n}}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_{n}}{n}\quad P\text{-a.s.}
$$
Now sandwich for $n:=\lfloor t \rfloor$
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{t}\left(\frac{X_n}{n}+\frac{X_t-X_n}{n}\right)-E[X_1]\right)\leq \sqrt{t}\left(\frac{n}{t}\left(\frac{X_n}{n}+\frac{X_t-X_n}{n}\right)-E[X_1]\right) \leq \sqrt{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{t}\left(\frac{X_n}{n}+\frac{X_t-X_n}{n}\right)-E[X_1]\right)
$$
Where the upper and lower bound converges to $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

For three random-variables $X_n,X_n',Y$ with $X_n$ and $X_n'$ converge in distribution according to a random variable Z. If $X_{n}\leq Y\leq X_n'$, then $Y\rightarrow Z$ in distribution.

Comment: Is this a question to be answered?